# How to set the georeference of a layer

Tags: georeferencing

I can't find an answer and it's probably because I don't know the terminology, so if you could include terminology in the answer that would be swell.

I have an image of some sort. I bring it into QGIS as a layer.
I have a non-geo-referenced layer that can't really be seen.

This image is actually a copy of another layer that IS geo-referenced.

How do I copy the settings/headers from the one that exists to the one that is not being displayed due to the lack of spatial information?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this
https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html

However, the applet is slow to load large rasters. The pixel location/points are the inverse of what one would normally think.

The top right corner of an image is pixel location x 0, y image height.

To copy the information from another raster, open the raster in question, click properties and copy the "information" to a notepad.
From that notepad you can get the Extent information.
The extent is the x/y of the 4 points needed.

Like any extent, measure, North of the map is More then the measure south.